# How are Android click events delivered?

Tags: android, event-handling, click

I am keen to know how Android's event handling and dispatching work. Code walk-through is an option, of course. But, if there's any document one can refer me to, that'd be great.

As a concrete example, consider a click event on a button. How does that click propagate within the framework? In case of multiple event occurring one after another, is there some sort of event queue, and a dispatcher calling methods on the events in the queue? What goes on under the hood? If not any document, if one can point me to the relevant part of the code I should look at, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge the parent is the first asked, if he can handle the event, otherwise he asks his childs who can handle this event ?

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup